# Time Series R with duplicate Items for daily forecast

Tags: r, datetime, time-series, forecasting, timeserieschart

I would like a guidance no how to plot daily data and use forecasting in R.

There are low purchase for Sunday and Saturday in this data. And there are certain weekdays that have no purchase at all. So its the obstacles for the analysis.
I have around 300 rows with various item name which the items are duplicated inside the column, but with different dates.
Example, I bought exactly 1 soap 3 times a week, at monday, wednesday and also sunday.
This is the example data table :

[image: Example Data]

My trouble so far is that it took me a long time to forecast manually using other statistical software, so I try to learn R from the start and see how it could save the time. The table above have been put into R, the `date` also have been converted from `factor` into `date` class by using the function `as.Date(data$Date)`

Usually i used exponential smoothing method, since the purchase are still low and sometimes out of stock, so not much of pattern are shown from the historical data. The output of this analysis is that i could provide a forecast for the purchase of the item daily in order to give instruction when should we demand an item.

Comment: See [mcve] on how to provide a reproducible example when asking questions on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First please consider adding a reproducible example for a more substantial answer. Look at the most upvoted question with tag R for a how-to.

EDIT: I think this is what you want before creating the ts:

```
data.agg <- aggregate(data$purchase, by = list(data$date, data$item), FUN = sum)
```

If your data is not yet of class 'ts' you can create a time-series object with the `ts()` command. From the `?ts` page:

```
   ts(data = NA, start = 1, end = numeric(), frequency = 1,
   deltat = 1, ts.eps = getOption("ts.eps"), class = , names = )
as.ts(x, ...)
```

Generally you could use the HoltWinters function for exponential smoothing like so:

```
data.hw <- HotlWinters(data)
data.predict <- predict(data.hw, n.ahead = x) # for x = units of time ahead you would like to predict
```

See also `?HoltWinters` for more info on the function

Reproducible Example for aggregate:

```
data <- data.frame(date = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1), item = c('b','b','a','a', 'a', 'a'), purchase = c(5,15, 23, 7, 12, 11))

data.agg <- aggregate(data$purchase, by = list(data$date, data$item), FUN = sum)
```

Reproducible Example for HoltWinters:

```
library(AER)
data("UKNonDurables")

nd <- window((log(UKNonDurables)), end = c(1970, 4))
tsp(nd)
hw <- HoltWinters(nd)
pred <- predict(hw, n.ahead = 35)
pred

plot(hw, pred, ylim = range(log(UKNonDurables)))
lines(log(UKNonDurables))
```

Comment: This is helpful, however the Items are duplicated, i need to plot it Unique ways without duplicated variable, so that it have only 1 Items with daily purchase plotted. @daniel-winkler

Comment: Just to clarify: Would you like the total number of purchases per day regardless of the item or the total number of purchases per day per item?

Comment: The item is also vital for the analysis, so i would like to see the number of purchases per day per item @daniel

Comment: The `aggregate` function with `FUN = sum` `by = list(group1, group2)` should give you a table with the sum of purchases of item A per date. Continue the rest of the example with data.agg instead of data (if that is how you named it).